# Can i convert a LambdaExpression to valid c# or even IL

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm using a tool that creates LambdaExpressions from a gui. I want the that expression as c# (or even compilable IL) so that I can combine it into an assembly for later executilon.

The [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body?view=net-6.0#system-linq-expressions-lambdaexpression-body) property returns a string that looks **like** c# but uses constants like True and AndAlso instead of true and &&. I understand why.

Is there built in way to convert that LambdaExpression, or any implementation of Expression, to a *.dll?

This is the output of the Body property

```
((((x.Hospitalizations != null) AndAlso x.Hospitalizations.Any(x => Equals(x.TreatingPhysician, "Dr Ash Williams", OrdinalIgnoreCase))) == False) AndAlso (Convert(x.Pulse, Nullable`1) > Convert(50, Nullable`1)))
```

and from that LambdaExpression class I can, of course, get important things like the type and name of the object

Comment: Hello, Can you add example string of those lambda expressions? Overall, you probably need to write a parser class probably. I don't recall any built in way regarding for conversion of lambda expressions

Comment: What does the GUI actually output? Can we see a paste or screenshot or something?

Comment: you may have a look at https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString

Comment: Check this lib [ReadableExpressions](https://github.com/agileobjects/ReadableExpressions)

Comment: I've updated the question with the string that I get from the Body property

Comment: But the `Body` property of *what*? What exactly do you get out of this tool? Can you show a screenshot of it giving you output?

Comment: @canton7 check the link behind the word Body in the 2nd paragraph. It's the .net LambdaExpression class.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen not what I was hoping for, but yes that answers the question

Comment: @SohaibJundi Yes. I'll be checking that out.

Comment: Right, but how does a GUI tool **output** the LambdaExpression? Does it give you C# code to construct it, as text you can copy/paste? Does it show you what the DebugView is? Just it just show you something you can click through in the UI? I mean if it just gave you the C# to construct it this would be trivial: just paste that into your app, and call .Compile() on it at runtime, so it can't be that. So what is it?

Comment: @canton7 I'm reflecting to get that LambdaExpression. I never said it output... "I'm using a tool that creates..." : )

Comment: So what is your tool, and what does it create from its gui? I'm none the wiser

Comment: @canton7 https://codeeffects.com/

Comment: Something like [this](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer)?